# How to delete PPA repository from dpkg

Tags: 18.04, updates, dpkg, ppa

I am a new user of Linux currently using 18.04 on my HP laptop with AMD processor. Some times ago I have tried to install JDK11 from this repostiory`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java` then `sudo apt-get update` and finally hit this command `sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-installer-local` after doing this I have got error package is not installed, fine I closed my terminal then yesterday I am going to install `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` then I have got this error every time when I use `sudo apt update / sudo apt upgrade`

The error which I got every time:

```
aus@aus-pc:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for aus: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (66).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up oracle-java11-installer-local (11.0.4-1~linuxuprising1) ...
Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz 
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script 
subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Note: I have manually deleted URL from **Software & Update Center** but I got this error every time please help me. 
PPA reference URL: [Path from I got the reference of JDK11](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/11/how-to-install-oracle-java-11-in-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/)

Thank you

Comment: After you get this error taken care of, you can also install this package using the "deb" package from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html instead of using the ppa. Then you can install the deb file using `gdebi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the package that is stuck:

```
sudo apt remove oracle-java11-installer-local
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can run: `sudo dpkg -P oracle-java11-installer-local` to try and manually uninstall it using `dpkg` instead of `apt`.

Comment: I have used your solution and it works fine. Thanks to every one

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you need to download the file `jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`. You can download the file [from here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html). You must click to accept the license agreement and then you can click to download the file.

Assuming the file is downloaded to your `~/Downloads` directory, run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```